# PHP POST from FORM with BUTTON

Tags: php, forms, post, button

Hi there can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code? Looks well but it doesn't work; it should launch echo by post after clicking Button.

So edited some of code now its looks like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "<form class='upload' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?low=1'>
<input type='hidden' name='upload' value='go1' />
<input type='submit' value='low' />
</form>

<form class='upload' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?high=1'>
<input type='hidden' name='upload' value='go2' />
<input type='submit' value='high' />";

if ( $_POST['upload'] == 'go1' ) {
    if ( $_POST['low'] == '1' ) { echo 'low1'; }
};

if ( $_POST['upload'] == 'go2' ) {
    if ( $_POST['high'] == '1' ) { echo 'high1'; }
};
?>
```

But still got errors:

```
[20-Jul-2013 02:00:11 Europe/Warsaw] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: upload in /home/file.php on line 12
[20-Jul-2013 02:00:11 Europe/Warsaw] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: upload in /home/file.php line 16
[20-Jul-2013 02:00:12 Europe/Warsaw] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: low in /home/file.php  on line 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The first problem is that your `action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?low=1'` puts `low` into `$_GET` array, not in `$_POST`. So use `$_GET` also, or `$_REQUEST` instead, or additional hidden field.
2) The second problem is that you don't check your array with [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Your form is loaded at the first run, it is not submitted yet, arrays are empty.
3) Do not forget to close the second form tag.

Something like that:

```
echo "<form class='upload' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?low=1'>
<input type='hidden' name='upload' value='go1' />
<input type='submit' value='low' />
</form>

<form class='upload' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?high=1'>
<input type='hidden' name='upload' value='go2' />
<input type='submit' value='high' />
</form>";

if ( isset($_REQUEST['upload']) && $_REQUEST['upload'] == 'go1' ) {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['low']) && $_REQUEST['low'] == '1' ) { echo 'low1'; }
};

if ( isset($_REQUEST['upload']) && $_REQUEST['upload'] == 'go2' ) {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['high']) && $_REQUEST['high'] == '1' ) { echo 'high1'; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you enable error reporting you will get the exact error, there is syntax error when typing:

```
$_POST('upload')
      ^--      ^--
```

change it to:

```
$_POST['upload']
```

Then, you can write this line to enable error reporting while you are working on your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And later when you upload to production server:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

or just comment it out

Answer (score 0):

I think your actions in your forms are using the wrong `PHP_SELF`.  I think you want to use the `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` variable.